# Swift regular expression format?

Tags: ios, regex, swift, pcre

I'm familiar with doing pcre regexes, however they don't seem to work in swift.

```
^([1-9]\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d{2})?$
```

to validate numbers like 1,000,000.00

However, putting this in my swift function, causes an error.

```
    extension String {
    func isValidNumber() -> Bool {
        let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^([1-9]\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d{2})?$", options: .CaseInsensitive, error: nil)
        return regex?.firstMatchInString(self, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(self))) != nil
    }
}
```

"Invalid escape sequence in litteral"

This is of course, because pcre uses the "\" character, which swift interprets as an escape (I believe?)

So since I can't just use the regexes I'm used to. How do I translate them to be compatible with Swift code?

Comment: just escape the backslash one more time.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Within double quotes, a single backslash would be readed as an escape sequence. You need to escape all the backslashes one more time in-order to consider it as a regex backslash character.

```
"^([1-9]\\d{0,2}(,\\d{3})*|([1-9]\\d*))(\\.\\d{2})?$"
```

Comment: This answer is not really complete. Some other characters need single backslashes.

Answer (score 8):

### Edit (June 2022)

From Swift 5.7, which you can use on Xcode 14.0 Beta 1 or later, you can use `/.../` like this:

```swift
// Regex type
let regex = /^([1-9]\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d{2})?$/
```

**Edit (Dec 2022):** Since this internally creates [Regex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/regex) introduced in iOS 16 and macOS 13, the minimum deployment target must cover that OS version.

**Advantages over `#"..."#`:**

- Your regex pattern is parsed at the compile-time, so you don't need to worry if your pattern is valid or not once your program is compiled
- If your pattern is invalid, the compiler lets you know specifically which part is invalid as the compile error
- Syntax highlighting is applied

So your code would look like this:

```swift
extension String {
    func isValidNumber() -> Bool {
        let regex = /^([1-9]\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d{2})?$/
            .ignoresCase()
        return (try? regex.firstMatch(in: self)) != nil
    }
}
```

---

### Original answer

Since Swift 5, you can use `#"..."#` like this, so that you don't need to add extra escape sequences for Swift:

```swift
#"^([1-9]\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d{2})?$"#
```

Comment: This is much simpler than double escaping! Thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something there is an unfortunate and annoying caveat of the June 2022 edit (Swift 5.7 updates to regex) of your minimum iOS support must be iOS16.0 

Comment: Oh, so sorry @BenjaminHall, I overlooked that. I edited my answer. Thanks!