# XCDYouTubeKit No signature function in player script

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, regex, url

I can't find a regex to match these Youtube links and I don't really know what I'm looking at

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BS3oePljr8

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&feature=related

http://youtu.be/iwGFalTRHDA

http://youtu.be/n17B_uFF4cA

http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=r5nB9u4jjy4

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc

http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc
```

I'm not sure if there is a regex I can put in here to cover most of these but I need help please.

Errors (When trying to load/play video):

```
[XCDYouTubeKit] No signature function in player script

[XCDYouTubeKit] Video operation finished with error: This video is unavailable.

Domain: XCDYouTubeVideoErrorDomain

Code:   150

NSLocalizedDescription = "This video is unavailable.";

NSURL = "https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?el=embedded&hl=en&ps=default&video_id=2BS3oePljr8";
```

Code:

```
  NSArray<NSString *>*patterns = @[@"\\.sig\\|\\|([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\\(",

                                 @"[\"']signature[\"']\\s*,\\s*([^\\(]+)",

                                 @"yt\\.akamaized\\.net/\\)\\s*\\|\\|\\s*.*?\\s*c\\s*&&\\s*d\\.set\\([^,]+\\s*,\\s*(?:encodeURIComponent\\s*\\()?([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\\(",

                                 @"\\bc\\s*&&\\s*d\\.set\\([^,]+\\s*,\\s*(?:encodeURIComponent\\s*\\()?\\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\\(",

                                  @"\\bc\\s*&&\\s*d\\.set\\([^,]+\\s*,\\s*\\([^)]*\\)\\s*\\(\\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\\("
                                 ];
```

There's also this here:
//See list of regex patterns here https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py#L1179

But this honestly looks like hieroglyphics to me so yea.

**Additional code to play the Youtube video:**

```
  XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier("2BS3oePljr8") { (video: XCDYouTubeVideo?, error: Error?) in
            if let streamURL = video?.streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.medium360.rawValue] {
                player = AVPlayer(url: streamURL)
                playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                let playerLayerView = UIView()
                playerLayerView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.page3View.frame.width / 1.25, height: self.page3View.frame.height / 2)
                playerLayerView.center = CGPoint(self.page3View.frame.width * 0.5, self.page3View.frame.height * 0.5)
                playerLayer.frame = CGRect(0.0, 0.0, playerLayerView.frame.width, playerLayerView.frame.height)
                playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                playerLayer.zPosition = 2
                playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                playerLayerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                self.page3View.insertSubview(playerLayerView, at: 2)
                player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                player.play()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(youtu(\.?be)?(\.com)?)\/(?:embed\/)?(?:watch\?(?:feature=player_embedded&)?v=)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})
```

seems to be passing our desired inputs, and my guess is that you might want to extract those IDs, which are being captured using this capturing group,

```
([A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})
```

and you might want to check to see if all desired chars are already included in this char class:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-]
```

and if not simply add those.

---

The expression is additionally explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/o7xmQP/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/o7xmQP/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

Or if we wish to capture various components of the URLs, we would integrate more capturing groups into our expression, instead of non-capturing groups:

```
^https?:\/\/(www\.)?((music\.)?youtu(\.?be)?(\.com)?)\/(embed\/)?(watch\?(feature=player_embedded&(?:amp;)*?)?v=)?(get_video_info\?el=embedded&hl=en&ps=default&video_id=)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})(.*)$
```

and our desired IDs are in the capturing group `$10` in this lengthy expression, which isn't really so complicated though to design.

#### How to design an expression for all URLs?

We would just list all possible URLs, then we'd first capture the 11-digit IDs and we would add optional groups `?` for different components of the URLs to the left of IDs, and that's it.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/X4E8F7/1/)

#### Escaping

It seems that for escaping metachars, we would double backslash, `\\` instead of `\`, for instance our pattern might look like something similar to:

```
^https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?((music\\.)?youtu(\\.?be)?(\\.com)?)\\/(embed\\/)?(watch\\?(feature=player_embedded&(?:amp;)*?)?v=)?(get_video_info\\?el=embedded&hl=en&ps=default&video_id=)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})(.*)$
```

You can further check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/XzHrbx/1/) to see how the escaping would change in the example that you have provided in the comment.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Reference

[Swift regular expression format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917893/swift-regular-expression-format)

[NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW32)

Comment: ok, would that look like this :  @[@"\\.sig\\|\\|([A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})\\(",

Comment: great answer by the way I just don't know what im doing.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess my issue is actually converting that into a form like this  @"\\bc\\s*&&\\s*d\\.set\\([^,]+\\s*,\\s*(?:encodeURIComponent\\s*\\()?\\s*([A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})(.*)$\\("